# Ruby query with 2 different jointable conditions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I want find all users who have particular LanguagesUsers records. Currently I'm trying to to query a join table, LanguagesUsers for all the instances where a user has 2 of the appropriate languages_id and level

To find where there is just one association, this works:

```
User.joins(:languages_users).where(languages_users: {language_id: 2, level: 5})
```

How can I include 2 languages_users in the query, where they are BOTH true?
(For example, I want `language_id: 2 level: 1`    AND   `language_id: 3 level: 5`)

I have tried this, but it returns an error:

```
User.joins(:languages_users).where(languages_users: {language_id: 2, level: 5} AND languages_users: {language_id: 1, level: 3})
```

This one returns an empty array, even though there are definitely users who have 2 languages_users that match this criteria:

```
User.joins(:languages_users).where(languages_users: {language_id: 2, level: 5}).where(languages_users: {language_id: 1, level: 3})
```

What is the correct format for this?
Thanks!!

UPDATE:
LanugagesUser is a join table between Languages and Users and has language_id, level, user_id

```
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

UPDATE 2: Since both answers have suggested an or statement, I do not think I'm correctly communicating this fact:

BOTH RECORDS MUCH BE PRESENT.
For example. I want to know what users have a LanguagesUser(language_id: 1, level: 5) AND LanguagesUser(language_id:2, level:1)

Comment: What version of ActiveRecord are you using?

Comment: @soupdog I have 5.0.1

Comment: Excellent, than you can take advantage of the new `.or` query. I will update my answer.

Comment: @soupdog I need both to be true though, not one or the other.

Comment: My fault, I misunderstood. Let me rethink...

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Great, then my second edit may help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
User.joins(:languages_users).where(languages_users: [{language_id: 2, level: 5}, {language_id: 1, level: 3}])
```

EDIT:
Since you are using ActiveRecord >= 5, you can use the `.or` syntax. The result is a little verbose, but it should work, and I'm sure you can pretty it up:

```
User.joins(:languages_users).where(
  languages_users: {language_id: 2, level: 5}).
  or(
    User.joins(:languages_users).where(
      languages_users: {language_id: 1, level: 3}
  )
```

EDIT 2:
I *think* I understand what you're going for now, more complex than I first thought, but I think you are going to need a nested query. If you first query the `languages_users` table and group them by `user_id`, you can apply a `HAVING` clause on that to find those users that have both languages. Then you select the user_ids from that query and use them in a simple query on the users table. Since you are using postgres, the following may work.

```
languages = [{ language_id: 2, level: 5 }, { language_id: 1, level: 3 }]
User.where(users_with_all_languages(languages)

def users_with_all_languages(languages)
  LanguagesUser.
    select(:user_id).
    group(:user_id).
    having('array_agg(language_id) @> ARRAY[?] AND array_agg(level) @> ARRAY[?]',
      languages.map { |x| x[:language_id] },
      languages.map { |x| x[:level] }
    )
end
```

Or, more simply if you have flexibility with the format of the language data:

```
language_ids = [2, 1]
language_levels = [5, 3]
User.where(users_with_all_languages(language_ids, language_levels)

def users_with_all_languages(ids, levels)
  LanguagesUser.
    select(:user_id).
    group(:user_id).
    having('array_agg(language_id) @> ARRAY[?] AND array_agg(level) @> ARRAY[?]', ids, levels)
end
```

I have done something similar, but not with two conditions on the join table, so `AND`ing the two `array_agg` conditions is the only wildcard I think...

Comment: Does the join table have a corresponding model, e.g. `LanguagesUsers` ?

Comment: Oh -- but your answer helped me to find the answer!! I changed it to this: `User.joins(:languages_users).where(languages_users: {language_id: 2, level: 5} && {language_id: 1, level: 3})`  If you'd like to update your answer I will accept :)

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that really should work... can you post the result of calling `to_sql` on the full statement?

Comment: What do you mean? .to_sql instead of .where?

Comment: In `rails console`, enter `User.joins(:languages_users).where(languages_users: {language_id: 2, level: 5} && {language_id: 1, level: 3}).to_sql` and post the response. I'm just not convinced it's really working in general, though it may have returned the correct result in your specific test case.

Comment: ` "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" INNER JOIN \"languages_users\" ON \"languages_users\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\" WHERE \"languages_users\".\"language_id\" = 1 AND \"languages_users\".\"level\" = 3" `

Comment: Right, so in the SQL you can see that it's simply using the second hash _in place_ of the first to perform the query, so it is still not doing what you need. I will continue to try and find a solution. Is there an `id` column in the join table as well? If not, you may need to add one.

Comment: the newest edit gives me: `undefined method `last' for {:language_id=>2, :level=>5}:Hash`

Comment: Sorry, I'm over-thinking an arbitrary part of the answer. If you have input that comes in the form `{ language_id: 1, level: '5' }, { language_id: 2, level: '3' }` then the latest update should work now. Otherwise, you could simplify the code by just passing in the `language_id`s and `level`s as separate arrays.

Comment: latest: (sry - my bad in dev it's SQLite, on production it's pg, if that makes a diff) SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: "@": SELECT "languages_users"."user_id" FROM "languages_users" GROUP BY "languages_users"."user_id" HAVING (array_agg(language_id) @> ARRAY[2,1] AND array_agg(level) @> ARRAY[5,3])

Comment: Yes, definitely makes a difference. I think you can use `group_concat` in place of `array_agg`, but I don't believe SQLIte has a "contains" operator ('@>') I would suggest (for reasons such as this) it's better to run the same database in dev and production, so you may want to use homebrew to install postgres locally and update your database config.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132546/discussion-between-soupdog-and-gwalshington).

Answer (score 2):

2 solutions
(note: rails does not have support for `OR` queries)

**1. Simple SELECT WHERE**

Use a long line of code like this:

```
User.
  joins(:languages_users).
  where('(`languages_users`.`language_id` = ? AND `languages_users`.`level` = ?) ' + 
        'OR (`languages_users`.`language_id` = ? AND `languages_users`.`level` = ?)', 
        2, 1, 5, 3)
```

**2. 2 liner WHERE SELECT**

First you prepare a query for selecting a list of `languages_users.id`s

```
languages_users_ids = LanguagesUser.
  select(:id).
  where('(language_id = ? AND level = ?) OR (language_id = ? AND level = ?)', 
        2, 1, 5, 3)
```

Then you use it within a query to your `users` table:

```
User.joins(:languages_users).where(languages_users: {id: languages_users_ids})
```

This will produce a single "WHERE SELECT" request to your DB server:

```
SELECT * FROM users JOIN languages_users 
  WHERE languages_users.id IN (
    SELECT id FROM languages_users  
    WHERE (language_id = 2 AND level = 1) OR (language_id = 5 AND level = 3)
    )
```

Comment: I'll try this out. I want to emphasize that it is not OR -- both must be true. But I will try that with AND. Also, why did you start with saying rails doesn't support OR queries, and then you proposed 2 with OR? thanks!

Comment: @Benji - neither one works. They both return an empty array.

Comment: `language_id: 2 level: 1 AND language_id: 3 level: 5` is just not possible. Because you won't find a record where language_id = 2 and language_id = 3. language_id cannot have 2 values. That's why you have an empty result-set. See ?

Comment: This answer does not address my question then. My question is to find where users have BOTH records present.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
User.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN languages_users lu1 ON lu1.user_id = users.id AND lu1.language_id = 2 AND lu1.level = 5')
    .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN languages_users lu2 ON lu2.user_id = users.id AND lu2.language_id = 1 AND lu2.level = 3')
    .group('users.id')
```

I don't have postgres setup so I quickly tested this in my mysql setup.

When coming up with a more complex query, it's good to start thinking in raw sql (at least for me), then see if you can convert that into a AR query.

What you are trying to accomplish is like this is raw sql.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  languages_users lu1 ON users.id = lu1.user_id AND lu1.language_id = 2 AND lu1.level = 5
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  languages_users lu2 ON users.id = lu2.user_id AND lu2.language_id = 1 AND lu1.level = 3
GROUP BY
  users.id
```

This way, you will construct a table like this:

```
users.id | users.* | lu1.user_id | lu1.language_id | lu1.level | lu2.user_id | lu2.language_id | lu2.level
   1        ...            1             2                5            1            1                3
```

The two `where` clauses with one `join` wouldn't work because you are setting up two conditions to be met by `languages_users` table in one row. But it will always only satisfies one or less of them.

**Edit**

So this goes further in terms of performance. I assume you have proper index on `languages_users` table (you will need to index the `user_id`, and combination of `language_id and level`.

But I've tested on a similar situation with 90m rows in the equivalent of your `language_users`, and 13m rows in the equivalent of your `users` table. Either the query in my answer and the subquery answer would take really really long.

So using the subquery, you will put a lot of loads in your ruby server because you will fire individual queries to fetch all the user_ids from two subqueries and use them to construct the final query to fetch user record.

I am not able to test the performance of my join query either because it wouldn't return me before timing out.

Comment: This also returns an empty array.

Comment: Would it have something to with .where returning an array of ActiveRecord relations, as opposed to just an array of say, user_ids?

Comment: see my edit. you need to do a self join, which I don't think you can achieve without some raw sql fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go step by step
The first condition is to have `language_id: 2, level: 5`
So we can have a query just for this condition

```
users_first_condition = LanguagesUser.where(language_id: 2, level: 5).pluck(:user_id)
```

Then we can do the same for the second condition `{language_id: 1, level: 3}`

```
users_second_condition = LanguagesUser.where(language_id: 1, level: 3).pluck(:user_id)
```

Since we have the user_ids for both conditions we can intersect both arrays and run a new query:

```
User.where(id: users_first_condition & users_second_condition)
```

If we want to prevent to run multiple queries, we can use sub-queries, so, instead of get only id's from each conditions, we can pass directly the relation to the Users' query:

```
users_first_condtion = Languagesuser.select(:user_id).where(language_id: 2, level: 5)
users_second_condition = Languageuser.select(:user_id).where(language_id: 1, level: 3)
User.where(id: users_first_condition).where(id: users_second_condition)
```

Comment: May work, but really not a good practice : pluck will eager load records and return an array. Your statements will issue 3 requests to the db server and some workload on the app server.

Comment: Yep, that is the reason why I put another option to prevent multiple queries.

Comment: So you need to fix it like this : `Languagesuser.select(:user_id).where(language_id: 2, level: 5)`

Comment: Can you run explain on the query? I'm curious to find out the performance difference.

Comment: So, the explain will depend in a lot of stuff, indexes, table's size, data scattering, and so on

Comment: I believe there's only one index here, the user_id

Comment: So tested this will generate 3 queries. Rails will just select `user_id` from both conditions as individual query, then fire the last one to fetch all the users.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User.
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN languages_users AS l1 ON 
          l1.user_id = users.id AND l1.language_id = 1 AND l1.level = 3").
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN languages_users AS l2 ON 
          l2.user_id = users.id AND l2.language_id = 2 AND l2.level = 5").
  where("l1.id IS NOT NULL AND l2.id IS NOT NULL")
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried :

```
User.joins(:languages_users).where(languages_users: {language_id: 2, level: 5}).where(languages_users: {language_id: 1, level: 3})
```

Comment: this will not work because the chained `where` clause creates `AND` condition, while op needs `OR`

Comment: Maybe I am confused, but doesn't the OP specifically asked for a `AND` clause ?

Comment: my bad. you're right. op wants `AND`. This wouldn't work because it's a inner join. op already tried what you suggested and it's in the question